# This app are using long polling?

Tags: javascript, comet

I want to know if this web app are using long polling or anything else "javascript trick":

http://typewith.me/2wicOjuefI

Is there a way to know that ?

Thanks ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, they're using long polling comet.  Open Fiddler and you'll see the requests.  The URL pretty much gives it away.

`/comet/channel?v=2&r=969379046853&id=184754471255&channel=longpolling&seq=15&timeout=10000`

In IE, the client makes a request and waits for the server to respond.  As soon as the server responds the connection is closed and another connection is made to wait for the next response.  This prevents memory issues that can occur in IE with unclosed connections.  It's possible in Firefox they just use multipart-replace.